# How can I make tuple of tuples?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make tuple of tuples!

```
a = ('Oct 27, 2021', 'Oct 24, 2021', 'Oct 20, 2021', 'Oct 20, 2021')
b = ('1',)

>>> h=tuple([a+b])
(('Oct 27, 2021', 'Oct 24, 2021', 'Oct 20, 2021', 'Oct 20, 2021', '1'),)
```

What I want is this

```
(('Oct 27, 2021', 'Oct 24, 2021', 'Oct 20, 2021', 'Oct 20, 2021'), ('1'))
```

I've tried to use the zip but didn't work!
in my opinion it should be easy, but I can't find the answer.
Could I get some help on this?

[image]

WOW

I've tried (a+b).... so sorry for that.
It should be (a,b) not (a+b)!

Comment: Just do `(a, b)` Or `tuple([a, b])`

Comment: Note that it's not `tuple(a, b)` just `(a, b)`. i.e. `tuple_of_tuples = (a, b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuples are unchangedable (see: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp). It means you cannot append, merge or extend them.

The only way to get what you want is to directly write them as:

`(b, t)`

Comment: Somehow it does not work..

Comment: perfectly works with `Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32`. What is your python version.

Comment: It does not work with Python 3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32